User Info API no longer returning email
Good day, I have been using the Banno OIDC user info endpoint for several years in a standard OIDC workflow in my application. Today I noticed in my logs that since 3/29/2024 approximately 200,000 calls to this API have resulted with a null email claim/property. Prior to 3/29 this had never occurred (100% of the hundreds of thousands of requests in previous years had this field populated).
Is anyone in the community experiencing the same thing?

Just to clarify, you're referring to the GET /a/consumer/api/v0/oidc/me endpoint, correct? Separately, was the null property value for email sporadic in returning null since the behavior began, or has it always returned null since the behavior began?

Hi, @JaimeLopezJr., thanks for the quick response! Yes, that's the endpoint that I mean. It does not always return null now, there are many situations where it returns populated. It's almost as if in the backend that field was made nullable on 3/29, whereas before that field was not allowed to be null.  Thanks again!

If you can get the x-request-id from the response header, that would be useful. Especially if you have several of them. They'll need to be relatively fresh (within the last few days) due to log rotation policies, but if you can get them then we can share with Engineering for analysis.

Sure thing, here are 3 that happened in the past hour or so;
c32a72f37dc28fb5d09d2f030b37dabe

0f09c8252db5337b72a4bf63f648ecbb
f92215c05ed967d936801eda66df0f9b

It looks like those users don't have an email defined in Banno, which is weird. We'll share these x-request-ids with Engineering and get their insight.

I added an answer with info from Engineering.

There isn't a guarantee that an email would exist on the core (for any of Jack Henry's cores).
That's why the GET /a/consumer/api/v0/oidc/me endpoint has the email property as optional in the documented response.(i.e. because it is not required).

Interesting. I don't see in that documentation where it lists the email as optional in the documented response, it doesn't have nullable: true like middle_name does. Either way, do you know if that is a recent change?

Technically, a property in Swagger/OpenAPI specs is only required if it is marked as one of the required properties in the spec file. In SwaggerUI, which we use to render the API Reference, that renders as a red star next to required properties).

This is not a recent change. You may just have been 'lucky' that you had not encountered it in the past.
